# Passing object parameters to functions c++

Tags: c++, parameters

I am creating a program that simulates phone calls and text messages. I am trying to pass the info from the class object 'phone' to my dialNum and txtNum functions to cout when the user assigns the two phone numbers as originating and receiving phones but I'm having trouble figuring out what to do.

This is my code so far:

```
#ifndef PHONENUMBER_H
#define PHONENUMBER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class PhoneNumber {
public:

   PhoneNumber(const PhoneNumber &);
   friend ostream &operator<<( ostream&, const PhoneNumber & );
   friend istream &operator>>( istream&, PhoneNumber & );
   void dialNum();
   void txtNum();
   void displaySummary ();
   operator int() const {return phonenumberval;}
 //  Constructor(int, int);

private:
   char areaCode[ 5 ]; // 3-digit area code and null
   char exchange[ 5 ]; // 3-digit exchange and null
   char line[ 5 ];  // 4-digit line and null
   int phonenumberval;
   static int ntext;
   static int nlive;

}; // end class PhoneNumber

#endif


PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber (const PhoneNumber &phone1){

    phonenumberval = phone1. PhoneNumber;
}

ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const PhoneNumber &num )
{
   output << "(" << num.areaCode << ")" << num. exchange << "-" << num.line;

   return output; // enables cout << a << b << c;
} // end function operator<<

istream &operator>>( istream &input, PhoneNumber &num )
{
   input.ignore(0);
   input >> setw( 4 ) >> num.areaCode;
   input.ignore( 1 ); // skip ( and space
   input >> setw( 4 ) >> num.exchange;
   input.ignore();
   input >> setw( 5 ) >> num.line;  // input line

   return input;
}

void PhoneNumber::dialNum(){
    int num1;
    int num2;
    cout << "Enter originating phone: " << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter recieving phone: " << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << " Calling number " << num2 <<"...call made."<< endl;
    cout << "The const int phonenumberval = " << phonenumberval;
}

void PhoneNumber::txtNum(){
    string txt;
    int textphone1;
    int textphone2;

    cout << "Enter orginating phone: " << endl;
    cin >> textphone1;
    cout << "Enter receiving phone: " << endl;
    cin >> textphone2;
    cout << "Enter text message to send." << endl;
    cin >> string txt;
    cout << "Sending message to " << textphone2 << " .....message sent." <<     endl;
}

void PhoneNumber::displaySummary(int a, int b){
    nlive = int b;
    ntext = int a;

    cout << "You made " << nlive << " calls and " << ntext << " texts." << endl;
}

}
int main()
{
   PhoneNumber phone, phone2; // create object phone
   char answer;
   int callCounter = 0;
   int textCounter = 0;

   cout << "Enter phone number in the form (NNN) NNN-NNNN:\n";

   cin >> phone;

   cout << "Enter phone number in the form (NNN) NNN-NNNN:\n";

   cin >> phone2;

   cout << "The phone number entered was: ";

   cout << phone << endl;
   cout << phone2 << endl;

 do {
 cout << "Enter c to make a a call, t to text, s for summary information, or x to exit. " << endl;
    cin >> answer;


        if (answer == 'c'){
            phone.dialNum();
            ++callCounter;

        }

        else if (answer == 't'){

            cout << "who cares" << endl;
            ++textCounter;
        }

        else if (answer == 's'){
            phone.displaySummary(callCounter, textCounter);  
        }

 } while (answer != 'x');

    cout << "You made " << callCounter << " calls and " << textCounter << " texts." << endl;

    return 0;
 } // end main
```

When I tried to pass the object these are the errors I got:

```
In copy constructor 'PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber(const PhoneNumber&)':
32:30: error: invalid use of 'PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber'
 In function 'int main()':
67:16: error: no matching function for call to 'PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber()'
67:16: note: candidate is:
30:1: note: PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber(const PhoneNumber&)
30:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
67:23: error: no matching function for call to 'PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber()'
67:23: note: candidate is:
30:1: note: PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber(const PhoneNumber&)
30:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: `phonenumberval = phone1. PhoneNumber;` - what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

## Issue 1: user defined cast operator

You define a cast operator with this code:

```
operator int() const {return phonenumberval;}
```

… which I guess you try to call with this code:

```
phonenumberval = phone1. PhoneNumber;
```

… but this is not the way it works. To call the cast operator, you have to do the following:

```
phonenumberval = (int)phone1;
```

## Issue 2: user defined constructor

In C++, as soon as you provide a user-defined constructor (which you do there by declaring the copy constructor `PhoneNumber(const PhoneNumber &);`), you lose the default constructors provided by the language. In your case, you lose the default constructor `PhoneNumber();`, which means you can't create a new `PhoneNumber` without giving a parameter to the constructor.

Just add a new constructor the `PhoneNumber` class, and it should be ok.

```
class PhoneNumber {
public:
    PhoneNumber(); // This is the default constructor
    PhoneNumber(const PhoneNumber &); // This is your copy constructor

// ...
};

// ...

int main()
{
    PhoneNumber phone, phone2; // This will call the default constructor, which has to be declared first
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I would discourage the  use of`operator int()`, I don't see how it is suitable for this problem. Better to just use `int getPhoneNumberVal() const {return phonenumberval;}` instead.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: I agree. Actually, I'm not even convinced by the use of `int` as a storage for a [prefix code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) like phone numbers, as leading zeros *do* have a special meaning.

Comment: Now when I try to run the program it says: /tmp/ccLcOnZQ.o: In function `main':
:(.text.startup+0x13): undefined reference to `PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber()'
:(.text.startup+0x1d): undefined reference to `PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Aaron I agree but I'm required to use the operator int() for this program

Comment: @cookiecrumbler: this probably means that while you've declared a default constructor, you still have to *define* it. In other words, you need something like `PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber() { }` somewhere.

Comment: Adding to @Arkanosis 's comment, the code you have given us does not include your declaration of `PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber()` (as far as I can see). Are you sure you have correctly copied-and-pasted to the code to us?

Comment: Yes I did but I had taken it out while I was going through compiling errors. Now for phonenumberval I'm getting a random number instead of the user input phone number that's put into the class object 'phone'

Comment: I guess that's because you are testing it with phone numbers starting with (at least) one leading zero, which in C++ means the number is written in octal and not in decimal. That's one of the reasons why I'm rather sceptical about the idea of storing phone numbers in integers.